# To which extent is swig "very lazy binding" usable?

Tags: swig, ogre

In order to quickly test some library, and to avoid the many seconds needed for a simple C++ program to compile, I'd like to quickly generate some bindings to my library, which relies upon Ogre.

Swig's documentation says it's possible to write an interface file with something as simple as

> #include "Ogre.h"

Is it really workable that way?

I insist that I don't need carefully crafted bindings, just some quick-and-dirty stuff that allows me to experiment quickly with various test scenarios...

EDIT : Here are all the info about what I already tried :

Command line :

```
swig -c++ -java -includeall -ignoremissing -v -notemplatereduce ogre.i 1>out.log 2>err.log
```

Interface file :

```
 %module Ogre
 %{
 include "../include/OGRE/Ogre.h"
 %}
 %include "../include/OGRE/Ogre.h"
```

stderr (last line, after many warnings and no other error)

> Unable to open file SWIGTYPE_p_Ogre__MapIteratorT_Ogre__mapT_Ogre__ResourceHandle_Ogre__ResourcePtr_std__lessT_Ogre__ResourceHandle_t_Ogre__STLAllocatorT_std__pairT_Ogre__ResourceHandle_const_Ogre__ResourcePtr_t_Ogre__GeneralAllocPolicy_t_t__type_t.java: No such file or directory

Many java files are generated, but the generated cxx file only contains 5 lines of comments.

Comment: The documentation doesn't lie. For a lot of cases all you need is a #include and %include. Try it and see would be my advice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I've tried that very lazy way with "Ogre.h" and includeall directive and I've run into an error about missing swigtype file and an empty generated cxx. That's why I wanted to know if I just need to further tweak my parameters (maybe include file from swiglib?), or if my whole approach is wrong (wrong tool for the job, etc...)

Comment: The approach sounds perfectly reasonable, but it would be helpful to see the interface you wrote to check for any issues and the exact error you saw (was it SWIG or the compiler that complained?)

Comment: Just updated question to explain in detail what I've tried... I've not jumped to the compiler stage, as the SWIG stage obviously failed..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, looks like the problem I'm having is not entirely swig's fault.

In fact, swig cannot generate its oh-so-long filename, as it's defeated by Windows's stupid limitation on path length (even windows 7 includes this limit). Putting the source in another shorter named folder fixed the issue (but I hit another bug later as some types are even longer).

Now I have to find a way to circumvent windows limitation.

EDIT : I have provided a patch for SWIG that circumvents the limitation by hashing the very long type names. AFAIK, it's not yet applied.

Comment: I'm curious, looking at Ogre and SWIG myself (on Linux). All you are doing is providing that simple interface file to SWIG, and it does it's magic on ALL ogre3d? Or do you need an .i file for each ogre header? Just wondering if it works it's way through the #include hierarchy automagically.

Comment: @galaktor : that's what I'd like to do, but I didn't manage to make it work so far... I managed to generate all java + cxx binding files, but I'm still facing some compile issues. I think the "normal" way is to provide individual .i files (that's what Python-Ogre did, I think), because you manually resolve problems in generation, but in theory, you could include the main header and let SWIG follow the #includes.